Some pictures are not in the DCIM folder in an iPhone
I have an iPhone SE with iOS 16.3.1 with 64GB, almost full with more than 2000 photos and videos, which I started taking in June 2023 until today. My problem is that it seems that only those starting in November 2023 are stored in the DCIM folder. That's what I see when I plug the phone into a Windows PC, but also, when I plug it into a Mac and open Photos to import them, it shows the same pictures as the Windows PC. Where are the rest of the pictures stored? How can I see them from a laptop?

Were any of the photos synced to the phone from a computer?

@Ezekiel all were taken with the phone
